# store data name equal each class name

Tags: jquery

I have some html structure like below and I have to store each container inner div text val to data, now I'm coding like below js, it works fine but just feel not so smart, because these code kind like doing samething store data name equal class name, but I have to type and check the typo... is it possible more simple to do samething??

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="aq">text</div>
    <div class="be">text</div>
    <div class="co">text</div>
    <div class="dp">text</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container1">
    <div class="aq">text</div>
    <div class="be">text</div>
    <div class="co">text</div>
    <div class="dp">text</div>
    ...
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="aa">text</div>
    <div class="bd">text</div>
    <div class="cs">text</div>
    <div class="dw">text</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="aa">text</div>
    <div class="bd">text</div>
    <div class="cs">text</div>
    <div class="dw">text</div>
    ...
</div>
```

js

```
$(".container1").each(function(){
    $(this).data('aq', $(this).find('.aq').text());
    $(this).data('be', $(this).find('.be').text());
    $(this).data('co', $(this).find('.co').text());
    $(this).data('dp', $(this).find('.dp').text());
});
$(".container2").each(function(){
    $(this).data('aa', $(this).find('.aa').text());
    $(this).data('bd', $(this).find('.bd').text());
    $(this).data('cs', $(this).find('.cs').text());
    $(this).data('dw', $(this).find('.dw').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('[class^=container] div').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().data($(this).prop('class'), $(this).text());    
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz8VR/)

Comment: what if between container and need to store data div not only one layer parent to child, doesn't know how how many. How to find parent from child?

Comment: just like if from parent find child it can use find(class)

Comment: @user `$(this).closest('[class^=container]')` Will find the closest `div starting with container`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[class^=container]').children('div').each(function(){
  var $item = $(this), $container = $item.parent();
  $container.data($item.attr('class'), $item.text());
})
```

Though, all the containers should have a common class to avoid the `class^=container` selector. Maybe you can do `class="container container1"`